# How to add an existing SQL user to access SQL Agent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add an existing SQL user to access SQL Agent? Having SQL Agent will let the user to access the SQL Jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of access are you looking to give the existing user to jobs in SQL Agent? 
 `msdb` is the system database that is used by SQL Agent for job management, including job scheduling, history, and alerts.  There are several fixed database roles in this database that allow access to jobs, ranging from read to execution privileges, and a user will need to have membership in one of these for job access.  You can see more details on these roles in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-2017).  Are you wanting to give the user privileges to run jobs?  Of these roles, the `SQLAgentOperatorRole` role is the one with the least amount of privileges that still allows for a user to execute a job.  To add a user to this role, a user must first be created in `msdb` for the corresponding login.  An example of creating a user in `msdb`, then adding this user to the `SQLAgentOperatorRole` role is below.

**Update for Login and User Comment:**

In the example below YourUser is a database user.  This is specific to a database.  YourLogin is a login which is at the server level.  For additional information on the differences between logins and users, review documentation for [logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017) and [users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017).

```
USE [msdb]

GO

CREATE USER YourUser FOR LOGIN YourLogin

GO

ALTER ROLE SQLAgentOperatorRole ADD MEMBER YourUser
```

Comment: what is the different between YourUser and YourLogin. Whether user is the SQL Userlogin Account?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer for clarification on this.

Comment: thanks a lot .. i was able to fix it .. thanks for the clarification

Comment: No problem, glad it helped out.